# swift2 : Path of image in sqlite manager not showing up on iphone device

Tags: swift, sqlitemanager

This path I keep in database in sqlite manager

```
/Users/james/Desktop/Travel/orginal image/TEE5883m.jpg
```

When I run in simulator, It works fine, But in iphone device is not show image.

I don't know why, help me please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a local path on your computer. iPhone simulator runs on your computer. That's why it can see the file. The device has no access to files on your Mac, obviously. You need to fix your code, the paths in the database should point to one of your apps folders, for example documents directory.